# Notice: Undefined index: core AND Notice: Trying to get property of non-object AND Fatal error:

Tags: php, undefined

I am trying to code a server in PHP and I am having a few errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: core in /var/www/pages/home.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/pages/home.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /var/www/pages/home.php on line 3 and the code:

The code is:

```
$core = $GLOBALS["core"];
$core->mysql->query("delete from `promotions` where `end`<=" . time() . ";");
$promotions = $core->mysql->fetch_array("select * from `promotions` where `end`>" . time() . ";");
if(!in_array("lobby", $promotions)) $promotions[] = array("chat"=>"Lobby");
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `$core = $GLOBALS["core"];`?  What is `$core` (in the global scope)?  Where do you define a global `$core`?  Where is this code ran from?

Comment: All you errors stem from the fact that `$GLOBALS["core"]` doesn't exist

Comment: How do can i make $core = $GLOBALS["core"]; exist ? and the code is ran from home.php from a source i am using called 'xatech'

Comment: @Jake1: What do you mean, "how can I make [it] exist"?  What do you expect `$GLOBALS["core"]` to be equal to?  Where do you define a global `$core`?  Where is this code ran in relation to that?

Comment: @Jake1 That's like asking how to make a building exist. It depends on what sort of building you want it to be.

Comment: Ok, how do i add core as a key in var_dump($GLOBALS)

Comment: @Jake1 `$GLOBALS['core'] = whatever you want it to be;` By the looks of things it should be some object with a key called `mysql`, which itself is a `mysqli` object.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is telling you that `core` is an undefined index. That means that there is no index named `core` in your `$GLOBALS` array. This means that you have not defined `$core` anywhere in your global scope before whatever function this is in is being run.

Consequently, `$core` cannot be an object. Consequently, by writing `$core->mysql` you are attempting to get a property of a non-object. Consequently, PHP is telling you that you are attempting to get a property of a non-object.

Therefore, `$core->mysql` is not an object either. Therefore, by writing `$core->mysql->query(...)`, you are attempting to call a method of something that is not an object. Therefore, PHP is telling you that you are attempting to call a member function (method) on a non-object.

Everything is perfectly logical and explained to you by error messages that are actually quite clear. Your problem is that `$core` is not defined. Everything else follows, like liquid mercury, flowing down a ... a sloping... thing.

Answer (score 0):

1) `var_dump($GLOBALS)` and make sure you have `core` in it as key

2) Does your $GLOBALS['core'] is some kind of mySql object?

Second notice is because core is not found and `NULL->mysql->query` is not valid

Comment: It's `$GLOBALS`, not `$_GLOBALS`.

Comment: no, i dont think so, ill try var_dump($GLOBALS)